# how to approach if statement or decision tree (that depend on previous actions stored, predicted)

Tags: r

> How to handle these decisions that depend on the previous actions ?

```
  PokerStars Hand #238165162773: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level I (10/20) - 2022/08/23 8:59:52 BRT [2022/08/23 7:59:52 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #1 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (500 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (500 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (500 in chips) 
Ruslanchuk  posts small blind 10
fractool: posts big blind 20
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [As Qd]
greenmass: folds 
Ruslanchuk: folds
Uncalled bet (10) returned to fractool 
fractool collected 20 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 20 | Rake 0 
Seat 1: greenmass (button) folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (big blind) collected (20)



PokerStars Hand #238165163895: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level I (10/20) - 2022/08/23 8:59:59 BRT [2022/08/23 7:59:59 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (500 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (490 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (510 in chips) 
fractool: posts small blind 10
greenmass: posts big blind 20
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [6s 5h]
Ruslanchuk: folds 
fractool: calls 10
greenmass: checks 
*** FLOP *** [2s Kc 4c]
fractool: bets 20
greenmass: folds 
Uncalled bet (20) returned to fractool
fractool collected 40 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 40 | Rake 0 
Board [2s Kc 4c]
Seat 1: greenmass (big blind) folded on the Flop
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (button) folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 3: fractool (small blind) collected (40)



PokerStars Hand #238165166436: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level I (10/20) - 2022/08/23 9:00:13 BRT [2022/08/23 8:00:13 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (480 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (490 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (530 in chips) 
greenmass: posts small blind 10
Ruslanchuk: posts big blind 20
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Qh 9c]
fractool: raises 20 to 40
greenmass: folds 
Ruslanchuk: calls 20
*** FLOP *** [Ts 6d Qd]
Ruslanchuk: checks 
fractool: bets 40
Ruslanchuk: calls 40
*** TURN *** [Ts 6d Qd] [Kh]
Ruslanchuk: checks 
fractool: checks 
*** RIVER *** [Ts 6d Qd Kh] [Ac]
Ruslanchuk: checks 
fractool: checks 
*** SHOW DOWN ***
Ruslanchuk: shows [4c Qc] (a pair of Queens)
fractool: shows [Qh 9c] (a pair of Queens)
Ruslanchuk collected 85 from pot
fractool collected 85 from pot
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 170 | Rake 0 
Board [Ts 6d Qd Kh Ac]
Seat 1: greenmass (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (big blind) showed [4c Qc] and won (85) with a pair of Queens
Seat 3: fractool (button) showed [Qh 9c] and won (85) with a pair of Queens



PokerStars Hand #238165173882: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level I (10/20) - 2022/08/23 9:00:55 BRT [2022/08/23 8:00:55 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #1 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (470 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (495 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (535 in chips) 
Ruslanchuk: posts small blind 10
fractool: posts big blind 20
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [2s 8h]
greenmass: folds 
Ruslanchuk: calls 10
fractool: checks 
*** FLOP *** [Qc 7s 8d]
Ruslanchuk: checks 
fractool: checks 
*** TURN *** [Qc 7s 8d] [9s]
Ruslanchuk: checks 
fractool: checks 
*** RIVER *** [Qc 7s 8d 9s] [Jc]
Ruslanchuk: checks 
fractool: checks 
*** SHOW DOWN ***
Ruslanchuk: shows [5c As] (high card Ace)
fractool: shows [2s 8h] (a pair of Eights)
fractool collected 40 from pot
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 40 | Rake 0 
Board [Qc 7s 8d 9s Jc]
Seat 1: greenmass (button) folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (small blind) showed [5c As] and lost with high card Ace
Seat 3: fractool (big blind) showed [2s 8h] and won (40) with a pair of Eights



PokerStars Hand #238165178913: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level I (10/20) - 2022/08/23 9:01:21 BRT [2022/08/23 8:01:21 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (470 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (475 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (555 in chips) 
fractool: posts small blind 10
greenmass: posts big blind 20
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Qh Kd]
Ruslanchuk: folds 
fractool: raises 30 to 50
greenmass: raises 420 to 470 and is all-in
fractool: folds 
Uncalled bet (420) returned to greenmass
greenmass collected 100 from pot
greenmass: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 100 | Rake 0 
Seat 1: greenmass (big blind) collected (100)
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (button) folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 3: fractool (small blind) folded before Flop



PokerStars Hand #238165183825: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level I (10/20) - 2022/08/23 9:01:47 BRT [2022/08/23 8:01:47 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (520 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (475 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (505 in chips) 
greenmass: posts small blind 10
Ruslanchuk: posts big blind 20
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [9h 2c]
fractool: folds 
greenmass: raises 20 to 40
Ruslanchuk: calls 20
*** FLOP *** [5d 8c 2h]
greenmass: checks 
Ruslanchuk: checks 
*** TURN *** [5d 8c 2h] [5c]
greenmass: bets 56
Ruslanchuk: calls 56
*** RIVER *** [5d 8c 2h 5c] [Ts]
greenmass: bets 134
Ruslanchuk: raises 245 to 379 and is all-in
greenmass: folds 
Uncalled bet (245) returned to Ruslanchuk
Ruslanchuk collected 460 from pot
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 460 | Rake 0 
Board [5d 8c 2h 5c Ts]
Seat 1: greenmass (small blind) folded on the River
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (big blind) collected (460)
Seat 3: fractool (button) folded before Flop (didn't bet)



PokerStars Hand #238165196347: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level II (15/30) - 2022/08/23 9:02:51 BRT [2022/08/23 8:02:51 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #1 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (290 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (705 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (505 in chips) 
Ruslanchuk: posts small blind 15
fractool: posts big blind 30
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Ah 2d]
greenmass: folds 
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (15) returned to fractool
fractool collected 30 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 30 | Rake 0 
Seat 1: greenmass (button) folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (big blind) collected (30)



PokerStars Hand #238165197915: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level II (15/30) - 2022/08/23 9:02:59 BRT [2022/08/23 8:02:59 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (290 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (690 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (520 in chips) 
fractool: posts small blind 15
greenmass: posts big blind 30
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Ad 6c]
Ruslanchuk: folds 
fractool: raises 490 to 520 and is all-in
greenmass: folds 
Uncalled bet (490) returned to fractool
fractool collected 60 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 60 | Rake 0 
Seat 1: greenmass (big blind) folded before Flop
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (button) folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 3: fractool (small blind) collected (60)



PokerStars Hand #238165199592: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level II (15/30) - 2022/08/23 9:03:08 BRT [2022/08/23 8:03:08 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (260 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (690 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (550 in chips) 
greenmass: posts small blind 15
Ruslanchuk: posts big blind 30
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Qd 9d]
fractool: raises 30 to 60
greenmass: folds 
Ruslanchuk: calls 30
*** FLOP *** [8d 9s 5s]
Ruslanchuk: checks 
fractool: bets 60
Ruslanchuk: calls 60
*** TURN *** [8d 9s 5s] [Qs]
Ruslanchuk: checks 
fractool: bets 186
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (186) returned to fractool
fractool collected 255 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 255 | Rake 0 
Board [8d 9s 5s Qs]
Seat 1: greenmass (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (big blind) folded on the Turn
Seat 3: fractool (button) collected (255)



PokerStars Hand #238165207723: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level II (15/30) - 2022/08/23 9:03:49 BRT [2022/08/23 8:03:49 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #1 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (245 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (570 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (685 in chips) 
Ruslanchuk: posts small blind 15
fractool: posts big blind 30
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Tc 9c]
greenmass: raises 215 to 245 and is all-in
Ruslanchuk: folds 
fractool: folds 
Uncalled bet (215) returned to greenmass
greenmass collected 75 from pot
greenmass: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 75 | Rake 0 
Seat 1: greenmass (button) collected (75)
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (big blind) folded before Flop



PokerStars Hand #238165211138: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level III (20/40) - 2022/08/23 9:04:07 BRT [2022/08/23 8:04:07 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (290 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (555 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (655 in chips) 
fractool: posts small blind 20
greenmass: posts big blind 40
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Ts 7h]
Ruslanchuk: folds 
fractool: calls 20
greenmass: raises 250 to 290 and is all-in
fractool: folds 
Uncalled bet (250) returned to greenmass
greenmass collected 80 from pot
greenmass: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 80 | Rake 0 
Seat 1: greenmass (big blind) collected (80)
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (button) folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 3: fractool (small blind) folded before Flop



PokerStars Hand #238165216534: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level III (20/40) - 2022/08/23 9:04:33 BRT [2022/08/23 8:04:33 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (330 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (555 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (615 in chips) 
greenmass: posts small blind 20
Ruslanchuk: posts big blind 40
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Ks 2c]
fractool: folds 
greenmass: raises 290 to 330 and is all-in
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (290) returned to greenmass
greenmass collected 80 from pot
greenmass: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 80 | Rake 0 
Seat 1: greenmass (small blind) collected (80)
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (big blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (button) folded before Flop (didn't bet)



PokerStars Hand #238165219118: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level III (20/40) - 2022/08/23 9:04:47 BRT [2022/08/23 8:04:47 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #1 is the button
Seat 1: greenmass (370 in chips) 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (515 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (615 in chips) 
Ruslanchuk: posts small blind 20
fractool: posts big blind 40
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [5c Ad]
greenmass: raises 330 to 370 and is all-in
Ruslanchuk: folds 
fractool: calls 330
*** FLOP *** [4d 7c 6d]
*** TURN *** [4d 7c 6d] [9d]
*** RIVER *** [4d 7c 6d 9d] [4s]
*** SHOW DOWN ***
fractool: shows [5c Ad] (a pair of Fours)
greenmass: shows [Qs Th] (a pair of Fours - lower kicker)
fractool collected 760 from pot
greenmass finished the tournament in 3rd place
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 760 | Rake 0 
Board [4d 7c 6d 9d 4s]
Seat 1: greenmass (button) showed [Qs Th] and lost with a pair of Fours
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (big blind) showed [5c Ad] and won (760) with a pair of Fours



PokerStars Hand #238165224009: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level III (20/40) - 2022/08/23 9:05:11 BRT [2022/08/23 8:05:11 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (495 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1005 in chips) 
fractool: posts small blind 20
Ruslanchuk: posts big blind 40
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Kd As]
fractool: raises 965 to 1005 and is all-in
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (965) returned to fractool
fractool collected 80 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 80 | Rake 0 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (big blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (button) (small blind) collected (80)



PokerStars Hand #238165225683: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level III (20/40) - 2022/08/23 9:05:19 BRT [2022/08/23 8:05:19 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (455 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1045 in chips) 
Ruslanchuk: posts small blind 20
fractool: posts big blind 40
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Jh 5h]
Ruslanchuk: calls 20
fractool: checks 
*** FLOP *** [6s 2c 9c]
fractool: checks 
Ruslanchuk: bets 40
fractool: folds 
Uncalled bet (40) returned to Ruslanchuk
Ruslanchuk collected 80 from pot
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 80 | Rake 0 
Board [6s 2c 9c]
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (button) (small blind) collected (80)
Seat 3: fractool (big blind) folded on the Flop



PokerStars Hand #238165228409: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level III (20/40) - 2022/08/23 9:05:33 BRT [2022/08/23 8:05:33 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (495 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1005 in chips) 
fractool: posts small blind 20
Ruslanchuk: posts big blind 40
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [9c Qc]
fractool: raises 965 to 1005 and is all-in
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (965) returned to fractool
fractool collected 80 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 80 | Rake 0 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (big blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (button) (small blind) collected (80)



PokerStars Hand #238165231138: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level III (20/40) - 2022/08/23 9:05:46 BRT [2022/08/23 8:05:46 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (455 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1045 in chips) 
Ruslanchuk: posts small blind 20
fractool: posts big blind 40
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [As Kc]
Ruslanchuk: calls 20
fractool: raises 1005 to 1045 and is all-in
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (1005) returned to fractool
fractool collected 80 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 80 | Rake 0 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (button) (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (big blind) collected (80)



PokerStars Hand #238165233467: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level IV (30/60) - 2022/08/23 9:05:58 BRT [2022/08/23 8:05:58 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (415 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1085 in chips) 
fractool: posts small blind 30
Ruslanchuk: posts big blind 60
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [9h Ac]
fractool: raises 1025 to 1085 and is all-in
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (1025) returned to fractool
fractool collected 120 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 120 | Rake 0 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (big blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (button) (small blind) collected (120)



PokerStars Hand #238165234924: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level IV (30/60) - 2022/08/23 9:06:05 BRT [2022/08/23 8:06:05 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (355 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1145 in chips) 
Ruslanchuk: posts small blind 30
fractool: posts big blind 60
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Kh Kd]
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (30) returned to fractool
fractool collected 60 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 60 | Rake 0 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (button) (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (big blind) collected (60)



PokerStars Hand #238165235906: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level IV (30/60) - 2022/08/23 9:06:09 BRT [2022/08/23 8:06:09 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (325 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1175 in chips) 
fractool: posts small blind 30
Ruslanchuk: posts big blind 60
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Ac 3c]
fractool: raises 1115 to 1175 and is all-in
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (1115) returned to fractool
fractool collected 120 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 120 | Rake 0 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (big blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (button) (small blind) collected (120)



PokerStars Hand #238165237298: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level IV (30/60) - 2022/08/23 9:06:16 BRT [2022/08/23 8:06:16 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (265 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1235 in chips) 
Ruslanchuk: posts small blind 30
fractool: posts big blind 60
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [4d Ah]
Ruslanchuk: raises 205 to 265 and is all-in
fractool: calls 205
*** FLOP *** [5d 7c Ks]
*** TURN *** [5d 7c Ks] [8h]
*** RIVER *** [5d 7c Ks 8h] [5s]
*** SHOW DOWN ***
fractool: shows [4d Ah] (a pair of Fives)
Ruslanchuk: shows [Ac Kc] (two pair, Kings and Fives)
Ruslanchuk collected 530 from pot
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 530 | Rake 0 
Board [5d 7c Ks 8h 5s]
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (button) (small blind) showed [Ac Kc] and won (530) with two pair, Kings and Fives
Seat 3: fractool (big blind) showed [4d Ah] and lost with a pair of Fives



PokerStars Hand #238165240435: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level IV (30/60) - 2022/08/23 9:06:32 BRT [2022/08/23 8:06:32 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (530 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (970 in chips) 
fractool: posts small blind 30
Ruslanchuk: posts big blind 60
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [4d Ks]
fractool: raises 910 to 970 and is all-in
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (910) returned to fractool
fractool collected 120 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 120 | Rake 0 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (big blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (button) (small blind) collected (120)



PokerStars Hand #238165241427: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level IV (30/60) - 2022/08/23 9:06:37 BRT [2022/08/23 8:06:37 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (470 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1030 in chips) 
Ruslanchuk: posts small blind 30
fractool: posts big blind 60
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Jc As]
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (30) returned to fractool
fractool collected 60 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 60 | Rake 0 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (button) (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (big blind) collected (60)



PokerStars Hand #238165242239: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level IV (30/60) - 2022/08/23 9:06:41 BRT [2022/08/23 8:06:41 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (440 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1060 in chips) 
fractool: posts small blind 30
Ruslanchuk: posts big blind 60
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Jh 4s]
fractool: folds 
Uncalled bet (30) returned to Ruslanchuk
Ruslanchuk collected 60 from pot
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 60 | Rake 0 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (big blind) collected (60)
Seat 3: fractool (button) (small blind) folded before Flop



PokerStars Hand #238165243565: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level IV (30/60) - 2022/08/23 9:06:48 BRT [2022/08/23 8:06:48 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (470 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1030 in chips) 
Ruslanchuk: posts small blind 30
fractool: posts big blind 60
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [7h 6d]
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (30) returned to fractool
fractool collected 60 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 60 | Rake 0 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (button) (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (big blind) collected (60)



PokerStars Hand #238165244465: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level IV (30/60) - 2022/08/23 9:06:52 BRT [2022/08/23 8:06:52 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (440 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1060 in chips) 
fractool: posts small blind 30
Ruslanchuk: posts big blind 60
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [Jh Ac]
fractool: raises 1000 to 1060 and is all-in
Ruslanchuk: folds 
Uncalled bet (1000) returned to fractool
fractool collected 120 from pot
fractool: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 120 | Rake 0 
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (big blind) folded before Flop
Seat 3: fractool (button) (small blind) collected (120)



PokerStars Hand #238165245587: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level IV (30/60) - 2022/08/23 9:06:58 BRT [2022/08/23 8:06:58 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (380 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1120 in chips) 
Ruslanchuk: posts small blind 30
fractool: posts big blind 60
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [4c 7c]
Ruslanchuk: calls 30
fractool: checks 
*** FLOP *** [Kh 8h As]
fractool: checks 
Ruslanchuk: bets 60
fractool: folds 
Uncalled bet (60) returned to Ruslanchuk
Ruslanchuk collected 120 from pot
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 120 | Rake 0 
Board [Kh 8h As]
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (button) (small blind) collected (120)
Seat 3: fractool (big blind) folded on the Flop



PokerStars Hand #238165251756: Tournament #3460445494, $1.84+$0.16 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level IV (30/60) - 2022/08/23 9:07:29 BRT [2022/08/23 8:07:29 ET]
Table '3460445494 1' 3-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (440 in chips) 
Seat 3: fractool (1060 in chips) 
fractool: posts small blind 30
Ruslanchuk: posts big blind 60
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to fractool [3d Kd]
fractool: raises 1000 to 1060 and is all-in
Ruslanchuk: calls 380 and is all-in
Uncalled bet (620) returned to fractool
*** FLOP *** [7c 2c 8s]
*** TURN *** [7c 2c 8s] [Jc]
*** RIVER *** [7c 2c 8s Jc] [9d]
*** SHOW DOWN ***
Ruslanchuk: shows [Qs 6s] (high card Queen)
fractool: shows [3d Kd] (high card King)
fractool collected 880 from pot
Ruslanchuk finished the tournament in 2nd place
fractool wins the tournament and receives $4.00 - congratulations!
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 880 | Rake 0 
Board [7c 2c 8s Jc 9d]
Seat 2: Ruslanchuk (big blind) showed [Qs 6s] and lost with high card Queen
Seat 3: fractool (button) (small blind) showed [3d Kd] and won (880) with high card King
```

```
 actions_notreatament <- c("greenmass: raises 215 to 245 and is all-in\nRuslanchuk: folds \nfractool: folds \n", 
    "Ruslanchuk: folds \nfractool: calls 20\ngreenmass: raises 250 to 290 and is all-in\nfractool: folds \n", 
    "fractool: folds \ngreenmass: raises 290 to 330 and is all-in\nRuslanchuk: folds \n", 
    "greenmass: raises 330 to 370 and is all-in\nRuslanchuk: folds \nfractool: calls 330\n*** ", 
    "fractool: raises 965 to 1005 and is all-in\nRuslanchuk: folds \n", 
    "Ruslanchuk: calls 20\nfractool: checks \n*** ", "fractool: raises 965 to 1005 and is all-in\nRuslanchuk: folds \n"
    )
```

For better understand to solve this I have to clarify some things
Every line was extracted with regex, everyline is a hand ID inside a tournament (that is what is called a poker hand history file .txt)
there are 3 players
every player sit on a place 1, 2, 3, and that seat does not change on that ID_tournament

```
all_names <- c("greenmass", "Ruslanchuk","fractool")
```

What changes is the position Button, Small Blind, Big Blind.
I know the position of all players (all 2 or all 3, because the game start with 3, and there is only one winner at the end)

```
Button <- c("greenmass", "Ruslanchuk", "fractool", "greenmass", "fractool", 
"Ruslanchuk", "fractool")
```

```
SmallBlind <- c("Ruslanchuk", "fractool", "greenmass", "Ruslanchuk", "fractool", 
"Ruslanchuk", "fractool")
```

```
BigBlind <- c("fractool", "greenmass", "Ruslanchuk", "fractool", "Ruslanchuk", 
"fractool", "Ruslanchuk")
```

There is more data that is not relevant now, actions_notreatament[4] the player "greenmass"  lost the tournament, so there is 2 players and the Button is also Small blind
the order of act when there is 3 players is first the Button,Small blind and BigBlind.

I have make pseudocode that illustrates all iterations, but its quite large code and can't see a way to do this with automated tools or string

## but I think I can do this with if

```
the Button can Fold, Call, Raise
the Small blind can Fold, Call, Raise 
the Big blind can Fold, check, call, raise.
```

And so on until there is 2 folds or 2 calls, or 3 calls. So the player will go to the next stree (on poker this is called FLOP) or if there is 2 or 3 all-in they will see showdown.

Comment: Are you trying to program a game or program a game simulation? Have you looked at the code behind the R packages `holdem` and `poker`? (All the R code behind the functions is on GitHub.)

Comment: Yeah have checked all, and does not do what I cant, its an parse regex based to more clean text, just that for now, but there will be various calculation on the steps and the propouse its and analysis tool all inside R ( a package maybe)

Comment: Are you trying to make a model that will follow a decision tree, or to display something from these logs?  For example, to show what options each player had when they made their decision as a way of displaying the log?  Can you provide a sample output that you hope to obtain if your first object `actions_notreatment` was put through the program?

Comment: Yeah, the goal its to fallow a decision tree to display somothing from these logs, you are correct sir, but its not to show the actions that the each player had, just to store the actual hand and fallow the tree and do calculations and display relavant calculation based on the tree(aka action of the player )